# Как обрабатывать фильтр заданный пользователем?

Tags: java

Данные берутся из файла CSV, в нём находятся таблицы которые нужно вывести в соответствие с фильтром введённым пользователем в консоль, к примеру "column[1]>50 & column[4]=Значение20", то есть по сути пользователь вводит условие как для условного оператора, однако в консоль через сканер.

Фильтры могут быть — отношения равенства: равно (=), не равно (<>), больше (>), меньше (<).
Фильтры могут соединяться отношением И (&) и ИЛИ (||). Также могут участвовать скобки для
обозначения приоритета и группировки. Отношение И имеет более высокий приоритет
нежели ИЛИ. Фильтр может быть не указан.

Comment: Подсказка: вам нужен [синтаксический анализатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Comment: 1) Закинуть данные в БД (хоть sqlite) и пусть юзер пишет туда запросы 2) Придумать свой язык запросов, написать для него парсер, мучиться потом с поддержкой парсера.

Comment: Если предпочитаете упороться с вариантом собственного парсера, то [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) вам в помощь.

Comment: Соглашусь с @anton создаёшь некий lexer который преобразует текст в токены,   токены записываешь в условия и реализуешь уже логику... Кстати я бы заменил &  на (и) || на (или) текстовою репрезентацию. Если прям совсем жестко надо проверять, с функциями и.т.д. Я бы уже посмотрел на встраиваемые языки, например lua. Он легко встраивается в проект, очень быстрый, гибкий и user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно согласен с комментариями. Хотел бы добавить ещё вариант - использование ScripEngine Api для выполнения скрипта (javasсipt, python, groovy, ...) из Java кода. Вот небольшой пример использования для groovy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // условие фильтрации - вводится пользователем в groovy синтаксисе
    String condition = " column[1] > 50 & column[4] == 20  ";
    // считываем данные csv
    String[] yourCSV = {"1,2,3,4,5","1,51,3,4,20"};

    // собственно сам движок. В случае c groovy необходимо подключать стороннюю
    // библиотеку. Движок JavaScript этого не требует.
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("groovy");

    for (String line : yourCSV) {
        // преобразование линии из csv в тип integer 
        Integer[] columns = Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
        // передача параметров в скрипт (binding)
        engine.put("column", columns);
        // выполнение скрипта и получение результата
        boolean result = (boolean) engine.eval(condition);
        System.out.println(result); // false, true
    }

}
```

Какие недостатки у данного подхода:

1. Валидация того, что ввёл пользователь. Единственный способ это проверить - выполнить скрипт и отловить исключение. При этом не факт, что текст ошибки будет читабельным.
2. Время выполнение. Пишут что долго, но это всё относительно.
3. Инжекция вредоносного кода.